# Password Checker pure js. How to check against the rules in Password Checker

Tags: javascript, password-checker

Hi I have a password checker but I don't know what code I should use for my program. I need my program to check against the rules but I don't know how to do that. I was hoping someone would know how to do that or at least help me in doing so. 
These are the specks of my program.

The user types in their desired password, and based on a series of checks, the system tells them if their password is a strong password or not.
For a password to be considered strong, it must pass the following tests:
A password must contain at least 1 capital letter
A password must contain at least 1 lower-case letter
A password must contain at least 1 number
A password must contain at least 1 of the following chars: ! @ # $ % ^ &
A password must be at least 8 chars long
As the user types, they should be given feedback on the strength of their password.
You will need to check each letter so see if the password matches these rules.

This is my HTML.

```
<div style="text-align: center;" style="font-weight:bold;"> 
<h1> Password Strength Checker</h1>
<br/>
The most secure passwords will have a very strong rating.
<br/>
The ratings scale range from: Weak (0), Good (25) , Medium (50), Strong (75) and Very Strong (100).
<br/>
<br/>
RULES:
<br/>
1. Your password must contain at least 1 number.
<br/>
2. Your password must be at least 8 characters long.
<br/>
3. Your password must contain at least 1 capital letter.
<br/>
4. Your password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter.
<br/>
5. Your password must contain at least 1 of the following characters:
<br/>! @ + # $ % ^ & * , ? _ ~ - ( )  
<br/>
Spaces are not allowed.
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="password" size="30" name="password" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="passwordStrength(this.value);"><span id="passwordStrength" class="strength0"><span id = "passwordDescription"><br/>
Please Enter Password <br/>
```

This is my JavaScript.

```
 function passwordStrength(password) {
 var rating = [
 0, "<font color='black'> Weak </font>",
 25, "<font color='red'> Good </font>",
 50, "<font color='yellow'> Medium </font>",
 75, "<font color='blue'> Strong </font>",
 100, "<font color='green'> Very Strong </font>"];

 var score = 0;
 var pass = "";

 if (password.length > 8) {
     score += 25;
 }      
 if ((password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) {
     score += 25
 }
 if (password.match(/.[,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) {
     score += 25;
 }
 if (password.match(/[0-9]/)) {
     score += 25
 }
 if (password.match(/d+/)) {
     score += 10;}

 for (var i = rating.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
     if (score >= rating[i]) {
         pass = rating[i +1];
         break;
     }
 }
 document.getElementById("passwordDescription").innerHTML = "<b>" + pass + score + "</font></b>"
 document.getElementById("passwordStrength").className = "strength" + score;
 }
```

This is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jYcBT/138/

Comment: Are you really using the PURE template system that you referenced in the tags?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? Don't just dump a spec and a bunch of code, you have to **ask a question**.

Comment: I don't know how to check the rules i want to check the rules against  what the user types so if the type in James2010.user it should check all the letters and symbols and say the password is not strong enough if they don't follow the rules.

Comment: What's the purpose of `password.match(/d+/)`? There's no rule that says the password has to contain the letter `d`.

Comment: Why do you have so many commas in `password.match(/.[,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)`? If you want to require a comma, you only have to put it in the character set once. You don't need commas between characters.

Comment: You should put the check in `onkeyup`, not `onkeydown`. Otherwise, it's checking the password from the previous keystroke.

Comment: that means \d is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and + means 1 or more times. So, \d+ is 1 or more digits. i have put that in twice sorry.

Comment: There's no backslash in it. it's just `d`, not `\d`.

Comment: yes  i forgot about the commas sorry about that and i will check the onkeyup instead of onkeydown.

Comment: ok i didnt know that but is there a way to check the users input against the rules.

Comment: The way you're doing it seems fine.

Comment: i have got it that when you enter the symbols or letters it adds to your score but i want it to say if you don't enter them your password is not strong enough.

Comment: Since the score starts at zero, it accomplishes that automatically. If you don't have those characters, the score will be low and the password isn't strong enough.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the user from submitting the form if the password isn't strong enough? Put the score in a global variable, so that the `onsubmit` function can check it.

Comment: so how would i do that then. it sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Take the `var` keyword off the assignment of `score`.

Comment: and how do i put my check in an onkeyup as well.

Comment: Use `onkeyup=` instead of `onkeydown`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Pure JS implementation without dependencies with configurable min length & calculated score https://github.com/lubosdz/simple-js-password-checker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your question?

However, I just fixed your special characters regular expression

```
password.match(/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\?\_\~\-\(\)]+/)
```

Remove the extra 10 points that you had, not sure why you added this?

change the event from onkeydown to onchange.

It works fine as far as i understand your flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/jYcBT/140/